# Details of Bhawani Mishra who build temple where goddesses speak

Tags: temple, tantra, resource

There is a temple of Goddess Tripura Sundari in Bihar where many people experienced goddesses talking at night times. I am quoting from [this article](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/travel/Bihar/Believe-it-or-not-deities-enshrined-inside-this-temple-in-Bihar-talk-to-each-other-at-night/ps73478145.cms)

> the deities present inside the temple speak like humans! It is a
> stunning truth experienced by several people that at night, when the
> temple closes for the darshan. Many people have heard noise coming
> through the walls of the temple as if the deities were conversing with
> each other. To find out the truth of these statements a team of
> scientists visited the temple at night, and concluded that there
> indeed words tend to echo within the temple walls when heard intently
> at night.

A tantric siddha named Bhawani Mishra built the temple about 400 years ago

> It is said that long ago, about 400 years ago, **a tantric named Bhawani
> Mishra** chose a certain place to build a shrine of Goddess Tripura
> Sundari and a host of other devtas. It has been a long tradition in
> this temple to worship the deities by using both Vedic and Tantrik
> practices. Tantra practitioners have an unbroken and unwavering faith
> in the power of this shrine.

I want to know more details about Bhawani Mishra. Bhawani Mishra is undoubtedly a great tantric and expert sadhaka.

Are there any articles or books available about Bhawani Mishra? Is there any lineage of Bhawani Mishra?

Comment: How cool ! I love this kind of stuff. Thx for posting this :D