# Tantric Guru Bhawani Mishra

Tags: temple, guru, bhakti, siddhi

Does someone have more information regarding tantric Guru Bhawani Mishra, who build the temple of Tripura Sundari in Bihar 400 years ago? I am very interested in his history, so can someone share more information regarding him and his family?

Comment: Welcome to HSE!! This looks like a duplicate question of this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/52702/647. Hence closing.